# Reading lines from a text file and splitting its contents

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter, readfile

For a Battleship game, I want to read values from a text-file and store them into variables.
Example of .txt file:

```
    8
    Carrier;3*2;3*3;3*4;3*5;3*6
    Battleship;5*6;6*6;7*6;8*6
    Submarine;5*2;6*2;7*2;
    Destroyer;1*7;1*8
```

First line denotes the size of my board.

The structure of the next lines denotes the ship, i. e. its name along with its coordinates on the board. For example: Carrier has coordinates: (3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5)(3,6).

The number of coordinates associated with a ship is fixed. However the line on which the ship is presented can change.

Right now, I try to create an array int[][] with the name Carrier where int[0][0] is 3, int[0][1] is 2,..., and do this for every ship.

Later, the board size which is always placed in the first line should be stored in a variable `int size;`.

So far, I have this code.

```
public void ReadFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    int lineNumber = 1;

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(lineNumber==1){ // Skipping board size for now.
            lineNumber++;
            continue;

        }
        String[] coordinates = line.split(";");
        String ship = coordinates[0];
        System.out.println(ship);
        lineNumber++;

    }

    scanner.close();

}
```

I tried using delimiters, split,.. but I did not manage to find a solution.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? The split on ; seems fine and you will know which ship you are parsing. After that you can split each further string in the coordinates[] array by * to get the individual parts (column and row?). Since I don't know what data structure you have to save the data I can't give much more advice.

Comment: You say you "try to create an array int[][]" but that is nowhere in your code. Even if your code does not work it should show where you want to do what, if necessary through comments.

Answer (score 0):

> Also the board size which is always placed in the first line should be stored in a variable int size;

So why does your code just skip the first line and do nothing with it?

Your logic should be changed to add something like the following to read the size of the board:

```
int size = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // to skip to the next line of data
```

Then you use your loop to read all the ship info:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] coordinates = line.split(";");
    String ship = coordinates[0];
    System.out.println(ship);
}
```

Edit:

> this String Array has null-values because the length (#coordinates) is different for each ship.

The String array from the code posted in your question will NOT have null values. It will only contain data that has been parsed from each line of data.

If you attempt to copy the data from this array to another 2D array of a fixed size then your logic is wrong. Why would you create a fixed size array when you know the length of the data is different?

> In essence, I need to store all coordinates from carrier into one seperate 2D array

I would NOT use a 2D array. Instead I would create an ArrayList that contains all the coordinates for a single ship. Then you need an ArrayList to hold all the ships. So the logic would be something like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> ships = new ArrayList<>();

while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    ...
    ArrayList<Point> ship = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < coordinates.length; i++)
    {
        // split the value in the coordinates array at the given index
        // use the two values to create a Point object
        Point point = new Point(...);
        ship.add( point );
    }

    ships.add( ship );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, however, it creates a array with strings, where coordinate[0] contains all the ship names (which is great), but coordinate[1] contains all first coordinates. In essence, I need to store all coordinates from carrier into one seperate 2D array, battleship in another one,... Furthermore, this String Array has null-values because the length (#coordinates) is different for each ship. Thank you for your Time, camickr!

Comment: Thanks alot. Considering my logic in the other classes is built on the 2D structure for my coordinates, I'm forced to continue using it (due to lack of time for the assignment). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    public static void ReadFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
        int lineNumber = 1;
        int size_board;
        int [][] boards=new int[4][0];
        int index=0;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            
            if(lineNumber==1){
                line=line.replaceAll("[\\n\\t ]", "");
                size_board=Integer.parseInt(line);
                System.out.println(size_board);
                lineNumber++;
                continue;

            }
            
            int[] board=new int[0];
            String[] coordinates = line.split(";");
            String ship = coordinates[0];
            System.out.println(ship);
            int z=0;
            for (int i=1;i<coordinates.length ; i++) {
                board = Arrays.copyOf(board, board.length+2);
                String[] coords=coordinates[i].split("\\*");
                board[z++]=Integer.parseInt(coords[0]);
                board[z++]=Integer.parseInt(coords[1]);
            }

            lineNumber++;
            boards[index]=Arrays.copyOf(boards[index], board.length);
            boards[index++]=board;

        }

        scanner.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option for you. This collects the ships and coordinates into a Map<String, List> where the string key holds either "board" or ship name and the List contains the array of arrays with the coordinates or grid size.

```java
  public static void ReadFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    int lineNumber = 1;
    Map<String, List> gameData = new HashMap<>();
    List board = new ArrayList();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = scanner.nextLine();
      if (lineNumber == 1) {
        String[] gridSize = { line };
        gameData.put("boardSize", Arrays.asList(gridSize));
        lineNumber++;
        continue;

      }
      List<String> values = Arrays.asList(line.split(";"));
      List<String[]> coordinates = new ArrayList();
      values.subList(1, values.size()).forEach(in -> {
        coordinates.add(in.split("(?<![*])[*](?![*])"));
      });
      gameData.put(values.get(0), coordinates);
      lineNumber++;
    }

    gameData.forEach((k, v) -> {
      System.out.print(k);
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(v.toArray()));
    });
    scanner.close();

  }
}
```

and here is the working repl:
https://repl.it/@randycasburn/GlaringSoulfulNet